# Why is my texture showing up backwards? How do I rotate it?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I make ROBLOX Gfx's and when Iimport the obj texture it showed up backwards on the woman rig. What do I do? I've tried looking up how to rotate textures but it seems easier on mac because I tried it on mac once before.

Comment: Hello :). This can probably be solved using the Mapping node. Can you please add an image of your UV editor and 3D viewport?

Comment: I've fixed it! Thank you for trying to help. :)

Comment: Congrats :). If you can, please add your solution as an answer, so others can learn from it.